# React Native app (background job) autostart on phone restart or app crash

Tags: android, ios, react-native

We have a plan to implement push notifications for our React Native app. We have to assure that app **is running all the time** since app user expects to see notification as it happens (background job would contact server every X minutes to check for new notifications - please advice if there is a better approach).

My question is: How to **autostart app on phone power on/restart and after app crash**? Is it possible to achieve this in React Native?

Comment: I would also be interested. Thank you